# How to expand an array based on quantity

Tags: php

I have an array which stores quantity. I want to convert this into individual array as described below

**What i have tried**

```
function expandArray($TICKETTYPE_TEMPARRAY, $readQuantity){
    for($i=1; $i<=$readQuantity; $i++){
        $TICKETTYPE[] = $TICKETTYPE_TEMPARRAY;
    }
}


foreach($TICKETTYPE_TEMPARRAY as $key => $value){
  $readQuantity = $value["QUANTITY"];
  expandArray($TICKETTYPE_TEMPARRAY, $readQuantity);
}
```

**My array**

```
$myarray = array(
  "TICKETPRICE" => "6.0000",
  "QUANTITY" => "2",
  "COUNTRYID" => "15"
)
```

**Expected output:**

```
[{TICKETPRICE:6.000, QUANTITY:2, COUNTRYID=15},
{TICKETPRICE:6.000, QUANTITY:2, COUNTRYID=15}]
```

Comment: Do mean like http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php ?

Comment: @Scuzzy But will it work if i push an array into it?

Comment: @Scuzzy i have tried array push but it doesnt work as expected

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It [works](https://imgur.com/a/YiSPjtb) on my computer

Comment: Maybe should the coding attempt that doesn't work and maybe we can fix that.  Also, if you are going to repeat the arrays `quantity` times, why keep the quantity element in the output?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, i wanted to remove it, but i had been working on ways to make the duplicated first based on quantity stated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$myarray = array(array(
  "TICKETPRICE" => "6.0000",
  "QUANTITY" => "2",
  "COUNTRYID" => "15"
),
array(
  "TICKETPRICE" => "4.0000",
  "QUANTITY" => "3",
  "COUNTRYID" => "9"
));

$output = array();
foreach ($myarray as $array) {
    $output[] = array_fill(0, $array['QUANTITY'], $array);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Output:

```
[[{"TICKETPRICE":"6.0000","QUANTITY":"2","COUNTRYID":"15"},
  {"TICKETPRICE":"6.0000","QUANTITY":"2","COUNTRYID":"15"}
 ],
 [{"TICKETPRICE":"4.0000","QUANTITY":"3","COUNTRYID":"9"},
  {"TICKETPRICE":"4.0000","QUANTITY":"3","COUNTRYID":"9"},
  {"TICKETPRICE":"4.0000","QUANTITY":"3","COUNTRYID":"9"}
]]
```

Or if you want a completely flat array:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($myarray as $array) {
    $output = array_merge($output, array_fill(0, $array['QUANTITY'], $array));
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Output:

```
[{"TICKETPRICE":"6.0000","QUANTITY":"2","COUNTRYID":"15"},
 {"TICKETPRICE":"6.0000","QUANTITY":"2","COUNTRYID":"15"}
 {"TICKETPRICE":"4.0000","QUANTITY":"3","COUNTRYID":"9"},
 {"TICKETPRICE":"4.0000","QUANTITY":"3","COUNTRYID":"9"},
 {"TICKETPRICE":"4.0000","QUANTITY":"3","COUNTRYID":"9"}
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Pv04M)

Comment: Thanks, btw, would it be possible to remove the quantity while creating the duplicates?

Comment: @KIRPALSINGH you could do it by unsetting the `QUANTITY` element before the `array_fill`. See https://3v4l.org/klQpY

Answer (score 2):

Simply array_fill and json_encode may help you.

```
<?php
$myarray = array(
    "TICKETPRICE" => "6.0000",
    "QUANTITY" => "2",
    "COUNTRYID" => "15"
);

$myarray = json_encode(array_fill(0, $myarray['QUANTITY'], $myarray));

print '<pre>';
print_r($myarray);
?>
```

Comment: Looks eerily similar to the earlier posted answer.  You have been ninja'ed my friend.